# Draw Line in Bar with negative stack in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my code i want to Draw a line in every bar of the stacked bar chart.If there is any option in Highcharts  to customize the chart like this

[image]

I need to draw that Selected portion line and circle in every bar.

My Code

```
    var categories = ['Atlanta', 'Columbia', 'Ohio', 'Great So'];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: { text: null },
        subtitle: { text: null },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: categories,
            reversed: false, //to change x axis starting from top or bottom
            opposite:true,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            tickLength: 0,

        }],
        yAxis: {
            min: -2250,
            max:2250,
            title: {
                text: null
            },
           gridLineWidth: 0,
           minorGridLineWidth: 0,
           lineColor: 'transparent',
           linewidth: 0,
           plotLines: [{
            color: '#ddd',
            width: 1,
            value: 0
        }],
            labels: {
                //step: 10,
                formatter: function () {
                    var value;

                    if(this.value==0)                                                               value='$-';
                    else if(this.value<0)
                    value='$('+Math.abs(this.value)+')';
                    else
                    value='$'+Math.abs(this.value);

                    return  value;
                }
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Male',
            data: [1000,1300,200,300]
        }, {
            name: 'Female',
            data: [1000,-300,-200,300]
        }]
    });
   });
```

Fiddle :[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/1hgvxp0u/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the extra scatter series with declared null points and lineWidth parameter.

```
series: [{
         type:'scatter',
       color: 'red',
       lineWidth: 2,
       data: [[0,0],[0,800],null,[1,0],[1,800],null,[2,0],[2,800],null,[3,0],[3,800],null,[4,0],[4,800]]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 100]
    }, {
        name: 'Year 1900',
        data: [-133, -156, -247, -408, 20]
    }]
```

Missing rectangle can be added by [Renderer.rect](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.rect) function.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9u3hgq42/

Comment: Your scatter plot solution is truly innovative and draws very nicely. It's also a lot simpler code-wise than what I thought up.

Answer (score 1):

Much like Sebastian Bochan's excellent answer, I approached the solution to your question by adding two "dummy series" (that have no meaningful data value) to your chart to emulate the lines and markers.

```
series: [{
    name: 'Male',
    data: [1000,1300,200,300],
    grouping: false,
    zIndex: 10
}, {
    name: 'Female',
    data: [1000,-300,-200,300],
    grouping: false,
    zIndex: 10
}, {
    // "dummy series" to draw the lines
    name: 'thin lines',
    data: [2495,2495,2495,2495],
    groupPadding: 0.6,
    color: 'gray',
    stacking: false,
    grouping: true,
    borderWidth: 0,
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    zIndex: 0
}, {
    // "dummy series" to draw the markers
    name: 'markers',
    data: [2495,2495,2495,2495],
    type: 'line',
    lineWidth: 0,
    marker: { fillColor: 'gray' },
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false
}]
```

For the series that draws the lines, I used the (default) column format. I set the `groupPadding` to 0.6 to thin the column to a line, set `stacking` to false so it wouldn't be included with the Male and Female series, and set `showInLegend` and `enableMouseTracking` to false so the user could not interact with them.

For the markers, I chose the line format for the second "dummy" series. I set the data to the maximum viewable value (going all the way to 2500 in your example pushed the markers off the edge of the chart). I repeated the `showInLegend` and `enableMouseTracking` attributes as well.

Finally, to make the line be even with the Male and Female columns, I used the `grouping` attributes. I set both of these to false to make sure they wouldn't be plotted together with the "dummy" column.

Here's an updated version of your fiddle with these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/1hgvxp0u/3/

[image]